# Загрузка файлов на сервер с помощью Ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript, файлы

Доброго времени суток Друзья! Возможно, уже где то был вопрос, и не один на эту тему, но по изучав интернет, ничего путного не нашёл. Задача состоит в том, чтобы через ajax запрос передать файл и сделать это нужно без фрейов, перезагрузок страниц и прочей и прочей ерунды, а так же сделать это нужно возможным на всех браузерах поддерживающих ajax запросы, без **file api** или как там его называют, как это сделать?

Можно ли получить информацию о файле, который был выбран полем

```
<input type="file" ..../>
```

например его имя я знаю как получить, достаточно обратиться к **document.getElementById('field_id').value** так мы получим имя файла, а можно ли получить другую информацию об этом файле с помощью javascript ещё до за загрузки на сервер тоесть без участия сервера и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аяксом не получится. В любом случае, придется динамически создавать фрейм либо апплет (flash | java) и грузить уже через него.
Информацию о файле тоже только jk'ом получить нельзя. И, кстати, value каждый браузер понимает по-своему. Кто-то выдает название файла, а кто-то - путь с названием. Так что будьте внимательны.

Comment: вот головой понимаю, что и правда нельзя аяксом сделать, но точно помню что видел реализацию..

Answer (score 1):

А если заглянуть в истоки и фундаментальные принципы загрузки файла асинхронно без применения технологии флеш, то это всего навсего такой вот код.

```
<form id="load-avatar-form" action="upload.php" target="upload_target">
    <input id="load-avatar-input-file" type="file" />
    <input id="load-avatar-input-bt" type="submit" />
    <iframe id="load-avatar-iframe" style="display: none;" name="upload_target" src="#" class="iframe-ghost"></iframe>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут 2 варианта, либо грузить во фрейме, либо флэшем перегонять файл в бинарник и на сервере собирать обратно. Даже не знаю, что проще - стараюсь такие приёмы не использовать и загружать файл с перезагрузкой страницы(т.е. не аяксом).

Answer (score 0):

А если использовать FormData()?
Создайте в коде экземпляр объекта FormData() и загружайте с помощью него.
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata)